# PagerJS refreshing navigates back to first page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pagerjs

I'm creating a single page application with KnockoutJS. It has 2 sections, home and history. 
At the homepage there is an button and with the onclick you navigate to the historical section.

```
function initialize() {
    model = new MonitoringViewModel();
    pager.extendWithPage(model);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
    pager.start('home');
}
```

When the button is clicked i'm calling a method in wich `pager.start('history');` is called. It works correct, but at the historical section when i refresh the page i'm navigating back to the home-page..

How can i make sure that when the page refreshes, the page doesn't goes back to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this kind of situation before.My recomendation for this kind of app, use Angularjs for this. It can easily handle page routing and this kid of historical problems.
If you can not change the technology now, you need to handle this by using cookies.